# What is the purpose of the three part circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, filter, voltage-divider, buffer

I'm studying for my final on introduction to circuits and came across a question about this circuit:

[image: circuit]

The question is:

1. Identify and describe the three parts of the circuit used for a measurement system for signal conditioning.
2. Describe the signal conditioning one intends to use the circuit for.

From what I can tell the R1 and R2 resistors are the first part of the circuit used to use a fraction of the incoming voltage. The second part is the voltage follower used to move all of the incoming voltage to another circuit. Lastly there is a low pass filter used to filter off the high frequency voltage.
The second question I'm not sure of the answer.

Comment: You're right about the first question. But without any other context (other discussions in your class?), it's impossible to guess the intended application, other than to say that you would use it anywhere you need the voltage reduced and the frequency content limited.

Comment: It's a poor question, because generally we'd use R1/2, or the opamp, but not both. Anyhow, what does dividing the voltage down before the opamp permit, that going straight into the opamp wouldn't? And what does using a low pass filter permit, that wouldn't be possible without it?

Comment: Neil is giving you good hints here. If R1 was 1Meg and R2 was 10kilohms for example, what would that tell you about the input signal, and does that answer Neil's question about going into the opamp?

Comment: The answer to 2., depends on the educational context and actual values.   The combination of low pass filter, voltage follower and voltage divider could be a front end of a high voltage A/D converter.

Answer (score 4):

@Neil_uk is right calling it a poor question.

The first part of the circuit attenuates the input signal to bring it within the range of the op-amp and whatever its output goes to.

The second part of the circuit is the op-amp itself. It's there to spare the designer the effort involved in applying Ohm's Law when there are several circuit elements involved. It's sometimes called an arithmetic-sparing op-amp: if it wasn't there the designer would have had to sharpen up his grade-school skills.

The third part is the RC low-pass.

You probably shouldn't be candid in answering the questions: think diplomatic. You don't want to offend the preparer of the question.

Follow-on thoughts: my "arithmetic sparing" characterization is what I think when I see similar circuits (very often). There are situations where the optimal design might very well be done this way. The questions you posed were given you to help prepare for your final, if I understand you. Your final won't have essay questions. Your questions must just be pointers to the types of analyses you should be able to handle in answering questions that might actually be on the final. Good luck on that final.

Comment: The opamp isn’t added out of laziness. While the opamp could be eliminated and the exact same transfer function achieved with R1 and R2 and an appropriately calculated capacitor across R2, what the opamp provides is a separation of the input from the outputs: the input impedance is just R1+R2 and unaffected by the RC filter, and the RC filter can be implemented without concern of affecting the input impedance.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the 2nd question: Depending on the values of R1 & R2, This arrangement allows for a higher impedance input, and lower impedance  output. In my line of work, the circuit is a simple version of the input stage of a DAQ (data acquisition) system. The voltage divider reduces the input voltage to the Analog to Digital converter, and has a first order low pass filter to get rid of the higher frequencies. However, there are many applications for this basic circuit.

Answer (score 0):

*Update 2021may27hkt0916*

I have had pointed out my serious conceptual mistake of describing the voltage divider as a "level shifter".  I need to think harder to see how I should modify my misleading answer.

---

I agree with the OP to the first question.

For the second question, the answer is:

1. The sign/polarity of the output signal is the same as the input signal.
2. its magnitude is R2 / (R1 + R2) of the input signal.
3. high frequency signals are cut off.
4. In other words, the circuit is intended to be used as a ***low frequency non-inverting analogue down level shifter*** (Note 1) .

*Notes*

1. Errata - my use of the name "level shifter" is simply wrong.  My apologies.  I must correct it later.

Comment: It doesn't level shift - that would add/subtract a fixed voltage from an input voltage. This is a buffered voltage divider. And it's not low frequency, it's a low-pass filter.

Comment: @TonyM, Ah my apologies to everybody. Your description of "a buffered voltage divider" is almost perfect.

Comment: Another term for the divider here is _attenuator_. TI even calls it a "non-inverting attenuator"... https://www.ti.com/download/kbase/volt/volt_div3.htm

Comment: @Erikr, Many thanks for your adivce and suggestion.  Your TI online "non-inverting attenuator" of calculating the resistor values of ａvoltage divider should be useful for newbie designers. Cheers.