# Measurement system

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, low-pass

My question is what the purpose of components in the **red** marked, **blue** marked and **black** marked area?.

[image]

Comment: Your question in the comment to the answer reminded me of a nearly identical question already [asked here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/567017/238590).

Comment: @AJN yes it does thank you!

Comment: @AJN Apparently they are doing the same homework.

Answer (score 0):

Red : Attenuator, it reduces the measured signal amplitude to a lower level suitable for the opamp input

Blue: Buffer, Opamp Gain=1 of the measured voltage, it separates the attenuator from the rest, so that loading the buffer output doesn't influence the measured signal

Black: 1st order low pass filter. It filters out high frequency fluctuation of the measured signal.

Comment: could you help me with this question aswell? Describe the signal conditioning you intend to do using the circuit.

Comment: @IPimp Is this a homework?

Comment: No sir, it from text book i do not really understand.

Comment: @AJN thank you sir!